# Auto-generated list-group-items not responding to active class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have one div with bootstrap's class list-group and its populated with the basic example Bootstrap provides, and I have another one which I want to populate with list-group-items obtained from ajax get request. The populate is being right, but when trying to switch between the active element it doesn't switch the active element.

The first div (example of boostrap) switch the active element correctly, but the second div (my own) doesn't.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button id="boton1">TEST</button>
    <div class="list-group col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          Cras justo odio
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-3">
        <div class="panel-heading">Geolocation
          <span class="pull-right"><span class="fa fa-globe"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="height: 400px;">
            <div class="list-group" id="ticker">

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var counter=0;
        var alert;
        $("#boton1").click(function() {
            for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
                counter++;
                if (counter===1){
                    alert = "<a class='list-group-item active' ";
                }else{
                    alert = "<a class='list-group-item' ";
                }
                alert+="href='#'>";
                // Titulo de la alerta
                alert+="<h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>";
                alert+="Alerta #"+counter;
                alert+="</h4>";
                // Texto de la alerta
                alert+="<p class='list-group-item-text'>";
                alert+="HOLIIISSS";
                alert+="</p>";
                alert+="</a>";
                $("#ticker").append(alert);
            }

        });

        $('.list-group-item').on('click',function(e){
            var previous = $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active");
            previous.removeClass('active');
            $(e.target).addClass('active'); 
        });
    });
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/txfjjzsm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You need to attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

```
$('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/en1ucfj6/.

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
$(".list-group").click(function (e) {
    $(".list-group .active").removeClass("active");
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
});
```